# No value for argument 'dml' in method call

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to set up a database which will store story information based on an id number. For now I am working on getting said information into the tables. I am learning python and sql as I go, so bear with me here.

Pylint tells me that there is the following error in reference to title.insert() and I just cannot figure out based on the docs what I am missing here:

> No value for argument 'dml' in method call

```
from ao3 import AO3
api = AO3()
work = api.work(id='1234')

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///ficrec.db', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
metadata = MetaData()

title = Table('title', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('title', String(256))
)
author = Table('author', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('author', String(128))
)
ins = title.insert().values(id=work.id, title=work.title)
```

Comment: Please include the entire error message including the traceback. There's nothing called `dml` in your code.

Comment: So, that's the thing. That is the whole message. I should have mentioned that it's pylint saying it's an issue, but if I run debugging everything appears fine. There is no traceback, nothing. Yet, like you said, there is nothing called dml in my code. So I am just confused. Is my linter confused? Or am I missing something important.

Comment: `pylint` is somewhat limited and sometimes throws spurious errors. If your code works, then don't worry about it.. I find linters more useful for style issues than detecting actual errors.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem. Basically, insert() requires a param which is `dml`.
Since it is not provided, pylint complains error like below.

```
[pylint] No value for argument 'dml' in method call [E1120]
```

It doesn't look there is functionality issue by not providing dml.
Based on briefly checking source code, the `dml` is generated by decorator

```
@util.dependencies("sqlalchemy.sql.dml")
def insert(self, dml, values=None, inline=False, **kwargs):
    """Generate an :func:`.insert` construct against this
    :class:`.TableClause`.

    E.g.::

        table.insert().values(name='foo')

    See :func:`.insert` for argument and usage information.

    """

    return dml.Insert(self, values=values, inline=inline, **kwargs)
```

In order to move on, in my case, I passed None value to insert() for NOW.
I'm not sure if it is good idea or not.
Hopefully, SQLAlchmey community handles this issue.

For you, try this way.

ins = title.insert(None).values(id=work.id, title=work.title)

Comment: That works to quiet pylint,and it doesn't seem to introduce any new errors for me.

FYI there is an open issue about it on the sqlalchemy github here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4656

Comment: @brendan thank you for sharing the open issue link.